# Excel Macro Copy cell range & paste data one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to look up a value given a list and copy the remaining row contents into the columns adjacent to the list. I copied some code from this site and have looked for answers elsewhere can't find anything. Every time I run the code it gives me a compile error "Invalid outside procedure"

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim lastDataRow As Long
Dim lastListRow As Long
Dim sheetOne As String
Dim sheetTwo As String

Dim listItem As String
Dim dataItem As String

Dim listColNum As Long
Dim dataColNum As Long

listColNum = 1
dataColNum = 2
sheetOne = "new_copy"
sheetTwo = "Historical_data_"

lastListRow = Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(Sheets(sheetOne).Rows.Count, listColNum).End(xlUp).row
lastDataRow = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(Sheets(sheetTwo).Rows.Count, dataColNum).End(xlUp).row

For x = 1 To lastListRow

    For i = 1 To lastDataRow

        If Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(x, listColNum).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(i, dataColNum).Value Then
            Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(x, 3).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If

    Next i
Next x
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you submitted compiles and runs without an issue.

When you see `Invalid outside procedure` you typically have code that is not between the `Sub` and `End Sub`

> The statement must occur within a Sub or Function, or a property
>   procedure (Property Get, Property Let, Property Set).

Also, you should check that your code is in a `Module` and not in `worksheet` or `workbook` code

Comment: I deleted the original module, inserted a new one, and copied the code back in. It ran fine then. Thanks for your help.